# Multiply without eliminate information

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, multiplication

I have a dataframe and I would like to maintain information. My data frame is like:

```
a <- c("a","b", "c", "d")
b <- c("e","f", "g", "h")
c <- c(1, 2, 1, 3) # multiply
d <- c("AB","BC", "CD", "DE")
e <- c(7, 5, 4, 3)
f<- c(2, 3, 5, 4)
g<- c(5, 7, 7, 9)
h <- c(6, 1, 2, 10)
m <- data.frame(a, b, d, e, f, g, h, c)
```

I would like to change e and f with the multiply of c * e ... c * h. How can I do it automatically without writing every single column?

Comment: For example: `m$e <- m$e * m$c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `across`:

```r
library(dplyr)
mutate(m, across(c(e, f), ~ .x * c))
#mutate(m, across(c(e, f), `*`, c))
  a b  d  e  f c
1 a e AB  7  2 1
2 b f BC 10  6 2
3 c g CD  4  5 1
4 d h DE  9 12 3
```

or if you wanna keep the original columns:

```r
mutate(m, across(c(e, f), ~ .x * c, .names = "new_{.col}"))

  a b  d  e  f c new_e new_f
1 a e AB  7  2 1     7     2
2 b f BC 10  6 2    20    12
3 c g CD  4  5 1     4     5
4 d h DE  9 12 3    27    36
```

---

or in base R

```r
m[c(4,5)] <- sapply(m[c(4,5)], \(x) c*x)
# or even simpler (as pointed out by @zx8754 in the comments)
#m[, 4:5] <- m[, 4:5] * m$c
```

if you wanna keep the original columns:

```r
m[paste0("new_", c("e", "f"))] <- sapply(m[c(4,5)], \(x) c*x)
#m[paste0("new_", c("e", "f"))] <- m[, 4:5] * m$c
```

Comment: As usual the much better answer ;-)

Comment: I have more columns in my original dataset and I have try your first solution, my error is: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..2 = ~.x * Dati$Volume`.
x `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Please edit your answer with your data which reproduces the error. It's hard to tell what's the problem otherwise.

Comment: This is my code: Dati %>% mutate(Dati, across(VW19_2021:AW18_2022), ~ .x * Dati$Volume) where Dati is m VW is e AW is f (I have more columns in the middle) Dati$Volume is c. Do you see some syntax error?

Comment: Try `Dati %>% mutate(across(VW19_2021:AW18_2022, ~ .x * Volume)) `

Comment: Nope, I will try to edit my question

Comment: I edited again, there was another mistake

Comment: Maybe simpler base: `m[, 4:5] <- m[, 4:5] * m$c`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mutate`, e.g.

```
a <- c("a","b", "c", "d")
b <- c("e","f", "g", "h")
c <- c(1, 2, 1, 3) #multiply
d <- c("AB","BC", "CD", "DE")
e <- c(7, 5, 4, 3)
f<- c(2, 3, 5, 4)
m <- data.frame(a, b, d, e, f, c)

library(dplyr)
m %>% 
  mutate(e = e*c,
         f = f*c)
```

Output:

```
  a b  d  e  f c
1 a e AB  7  2 1
2 b f BC 10  6 2
3 c g CD  4  5 1
4 d h DE  9 12 3
```

Answer (score 1):

base R solution:

```
m[,4:5] <- sapply(m[4:5], "*", c)
m
```

```
  a b  d  e  f c
1 a e AB  7  2 1
2 b f BC 10  6 2
3 c g CD  4  5 1
4 d h DE  9 12 3
```